# In Mono For Droid How to move ImageView when I touch it?

Tags: xamarin.android, android-imageview, ontouchlistener

I'm using Mono-For-Droid. I have an `ImageView` and want to move it to follow my finger when I touch it and stop moving when I release my finger.

Here is my code, please advice how do it?

```java
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.Content.Res;


[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = Android.Manifest.Permission.SystemAlertWindow)]
namespace ExtremeKeyboard
{
    [Service]
    public class ChatheadService: Android.App.Service
    {
        System.Threading.Timer _timer;

        private IWindowManager windowManager;
        private ImageView ReminderHead;
        private Drawable icon;
        private Android.Views.WindowManagerLayoutParams LOParams;

        public override void OnStart(Android.Content.Intent intent, int startId)
        {
            base.OnStart(intent, startId);

            var windowService = this.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.WindowService);
            var windowManager = windowService.JavaCast<Android.Views.IWindowManager>();

            ReminderHead = new ImageView(this);
            ReminderHead.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Icon);

            LOParams = new Android.Views.WindowManagerLayoutParams(
                Android.Views.WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent,
                Android.Views.WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent,
                Android.Views.WindowManagerTypes.Phone,
                Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags.NotFocusable,
                Android.Graphics.Format.Translucent);
            LOParams.Gravity = GravityFlags.Top | GravityFlags.Left;
            LOParams.X = 0;
            LOParams.Y = 100;            

            windowManager.AddView(ReminderHead, LOParams);
        }

        public override Android.OS.IBinder OnBind(Android.Content.Intent intent)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats wrong, why no body is answering?

Comment: You don't show any effort into solving the problem yourself. You also don't show that you have researched the topic. There are loads of answers on how to do this in Android and they are easily ported to the C# counterpart.